# UITableView height different between XCode and the real display (simulator and device) using monotouch

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios

I've created an UIView and modified with XCode :

[image]

But the resultant display on simulator and device is :

[image]

So, there is some property or anything in order to table maintain the height defined on the XCode edition? Note that the table has a bigger than the table on simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the section height, header and footer:

[image: XCode Screenshot]

It is a bit hard to see what is going on in your picture, but make sure you are making use of sections--it almost looks like you have multiple `UITableViews`.  You should only have to use one tableview for your UI here.

A second thing to check is those `UISearchBars`.  Are they meant to be there?

Comment: I've forget mention but as you can see in the first picture, there are two tables and both of them are displaying with a minor height. I'm not using sections, but I'll check if setting section heigh to 1 helps me.

Comment: About the search bars, yes they must be there, because the design. Each table has a search bar on header in order to hide on initial display (setting te scroll to 0 in each table)

Comment: What is your `UIView` `AutoResizingMask` set for? on each of the tables?  It sounds like the whole view is getting stretched and your tables are not stretching.  This would make the black areas appear taller.

Comment: tblSup.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin;
   tblNews.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin;  works for me on the ViewDidLoad event of the View. But I do not  understand the reason for that. I've have to read avout that property. Thanks

Comment: If the size of the parent view changes, it enforces what happens to the view.  So it could dock to the right, left, stretch, etc.  Here is a decent article: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html